# How to iterate arraylist of arrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I Have a list which is in

```
[
    [SAM, 12/01/2015, 9A-6P], 
    [JAM, 12/02/2015, 9A-6P]
]
```

I need to iterate it.I tried the below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < list4.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("List" + list4.get(i).toString());
}
//this is giving me [SAM, 12/01/2015, 9A-6P]
```

but I want to iterate the above one also `[SAM, 12/01/2015, 9A-6P]`.

Can anybody have idea?

Comment: 1] your code should be iterating over each entry of the top-level list, so I'm not quite sure how you're **not** getting both "rows" (check your output again).  2] `list4` is a _terrible_ name for a variable, try to find something more descriptive.  3] If possible, you should be de-serializing what is obviously some form of data into a better object.  For one thing, it would help to make your dates unambiguous.

Answer (score 8):

You can and should use the fact that every `List` is also an `Iterable`. So you can use this:

```
// Idk what you list actually contains
// So I just use Object
List<List<Object>> listOfLists; 
for(List<Object> aList : listOfLists) {
    for(Object object : aList) {
        // Do whatever you want with the object, e.g.
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried your case with below example. Hope it helps

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IterateList {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("SAM");
    list1.add("12/01/2015");
    list1.add("9A-6P");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("JAM");
    list2.add("12/01/2015");
    list2.add("9A-6P");

    myList.add(list1);
    myList.add(list2);

    for (List list : myList) {
      for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Output: 
SAM 
12/01/2015
9A-6P
JAM
12/01/2015
9A-6P